# TI-Nspire programming (TI-Basic)

Tags: ti-basic

I have a TI-Nspire, and I am trying to program a Pythagorean theorem program. (I would enter zero for the unsolved side)

```
:RequestStr "A Side",a
:RequestStr "B Side",b
:RequestStr "C Side",c
:IF a=0 THEN
:Disp "A=",root(c^2-b^2)
:ENDIF
:IF b=0 THEN
:Disp "B=",root(c^2-a^2)
:ENDIF
:IF c=0 THEN
:Disp "C=",root(a^2+b^2)
:ENDIF
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Also ti-basic on the Nspire is more limited than on ti-84s. I would suggest just writing C or python code and running it though ndless

Comment: Sorry, my problem was that it was inputting the values for a,b, and; but it wasn’t following through with the if...then statements. I think I’ll try Request instread of RequestStr

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with TI-Nspires, but for other calculators, the Pythagorean theorem can be done two ways:

To find the hypotenuse

```
Prompt A,B
Disp √(A²+B²)
```

To find another side (sides A and B are interchangeable in this case:

```
Prompt C,A
Disp √(C²-A²)
```

That is the simplest way to do it, again this all depends on if you know how to take advantage of the TI-Nspire's features.

Edit: Oh and from what I see, you want the unkown side to be equivalent to 0, so that, again, in TI-Basic, is:

```
Prompt A,B,C
If A=0
Disp √(C²-B²)
```

These next two lines are optional, as long as you know that A could be B, or vice versa:

```
If B=0
Disp √(C²-A²)
If C=0
Disp √(A²+B²)
```

BTW: the `√` is the square root symbol.